# specify custom url to gplus one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have this code

```
<div class="google_button">
   <g:plusone size="medium" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
   <% case I18n.locale.to_s %>
   <% when 'en' %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <% when 'es'%>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      window.___gcfg = {lang: 'es'};
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
     </script>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

I have in a variable `url` a url:

```
url = "http://www.mydomain.com/my_custom_url"
```

I want add to this google plus button this url variable.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `google_plus_button + url = true;` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url). It's a little confusing, but you just need to put the URL as the href attribute of the `<g:plusone>` tag. For instance:

```
<g:plusone size="medium" annotation="none" href="the url!"></g:plusone>
```

Comment: This is correct; however, the best method is to set canonical URLs for the page. This has benefits for Google Search optimization also in addition to setting the +1 URL. This help topic describes canonicalization: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066