# Single page application and social media link preview best practices?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, single-page-application

I have a new single page application which on page load is pretty much blank until related asynchronous data is loaded. When a link is pasted into the share field on Facebook, the link preview has no image and the text content is raw JSON. So that doesn't look very nice.

Google+ handles this a little bit better, giving me the page title and description but no image. At this time making the application crawl-able isn't a primary concern of ours. But having it look a little bit better on social media sites is.

Having both wouldn't be so bad but I'm unsure how best to tackle the problem. It is a Rails application with a heavy javascript powered front-end. It would be great if we could at least have the company logo and a description that relates to the linked page.

I've read some people try to read where the request is coming from and render different content based on that information. Or, possibly a logo and some descriptive text could be rendered on the page in the background by the server.

I wonder if there are Gems, best practices already available, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Facebook, you can use this meta-tag on the page to force an image when this URL is shared ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

Looks like it's possible with Google+ as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13312956/844726

Comment: Oh that is so awesome, was looking for a page for best practices just like that.